# Timestamp regexp in Elasticsearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elastalert

My goal is to make an alert in ElastAlert for this scenario: no events has occured between midnight and 2 am. (for any date). The problem is how to make a query to Elasticsearch that matches any date but a specific time, because you cannot use regexp or wildcard on timestamp of type 'date'. Any suggestions?

This code returns "Parse failure":

```
"range": {
  "timestamp": {
    "gte": "20[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T00:00:00.000Z",
    "lt": "20[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T02:00:00.000Z"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please share for us to help you better

Comment: In regex, `?` is a quantifier, and it is not allowed  to quantify a quantifier. So, to match any digit, you may use `[0-9]`. Does that help? `gte": "20[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T00:00:00[.]000Z",`?

Comment: Ok, you're right: the '?' should be '.' as of [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html). Correcting it.

Comment: And `.` should be escaped or used inside `[]` (`[.]`) or it will match any symbol but a newline.

Comment: I still think the issue is that it is not possible to combine regexp and timestamps. I suspect that the timestamp actually is an Epoch time, so regexping in the middle of the date makes a far too complex expression in Epoch time.

Comment: You should search for the right documentation and fix the code to learn where you can use a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have the right to write custom rules, so my solution was to make changes in logstash. Added the field hour_of_day, where the value is derived from the timestamp. Thus we are able to create a flatline rule with a filter like this:

```
filter:
 - query:
      query_string:
        query: "hour_of_day: 0 OR hour_of_day: 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Handling it in a custom rule is ideal.

I wrote the following to do the same kind of filtering:
Note, the dependencies used (dateutil, elastalert.utils) are already bundled with the elastalert framework.

```python
import dateutil.parser

from ruletypes import RuleType

# elastalert.util includes useful utility functions
# such as converting from timestamp to datetime obj
from util import ts_to_dt

# Modified version of http://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/adding_rules.html#tutorial
# to catch events happening outside a certain time range
class OutOfTimeRangeRule(RuleType):
    """ Match if input time is outside the given range """

    # Time range specified by including the following properties in the rule:
    required_options = set(['time_start', 'time_end'])

    # add_data will be called each time Elasticsearch is queried.
    # data is a list of documents from Elasticsearch, sorted by timestamp,
    # including all the fields that the config specifies with "include"
    def add_data(self, data):
        for document in data:
            # Convert the timestamp to a time object
            login_time = document['@timestamp'].time()

            # Convert time_start and time_end to time objects
            time_start = dateutil.parser.parse(self.rules['time_start']).time()
            time_end = dateutil.parser.parse(self.rules['time_end']).time()

            # If time is outside office hours
            if login_time < time_start or login_time > time_end:

                # To add a match, use self.add_match
                self.add_match(document)

    # The results of get_match_str will appear in the alert text
    def get_match_str(self, match):
        return "logged in outside %s and %s" % (self.rules['time_start'], self.rules['time_end'])

    def garbage_collect(self, timestamp):
        pass
```